# How to test whether a Linux binary was compiled as position independent code?

Tags: linux, security, fedora, executable

I recently learned that (at least on Fedora and Red Hat Enterprise Linux), executable programs that are compiled as Position Independent Executables (PIE) receive stronger address space randomization (ASLR) protection.

So: How do I test whether a particular executable was compiled as a Position Independent Executable, on Linux?

Comment: Not sure about 32-bit, but [on x86_64 code is position independent by default](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2011/11/11/position-independent-code-pic-in-shared-libraries-on-x64/). And of course all the system packages are compiled this way on either arch.

Comment: @MichaelHampton, I don't think that's right.  (Be careful about the difference between an executable binary and a shared library; your statement might be right for shared libraries, but I don't think it's right for executables.)  Even on x86_64, binaries do not appear to be PIE by default.  I just wrote a small test program, and on x86_64, it was not compiled as PIE.  I think you have to pass the `-pie -fpie` special compiler flags to compile a program as a PIE.  That link had other interesting information, though -- thank you!

Comment: This guy has a bash script for detection: http://blog.fpmurphy.com/2008/06/position-independent-executables.html

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can use the `perl` script contained in the `hardening-check` package, [available in Fedora](https://admin.fedoraproject.org/pkgdb/acls/name/hardening-check) and [Debian](http://packages.debian.org/wheezy/hardening-includes) (as `hardening-includes`). Read this [Debian wiki page](https://wiki.debian.org/HardeningWalkthrough) for details on what compile flags are checked. It's Debian specific, but the theory applies to Red Hat as well.

Example:

```
$ hardening-check $(which sshd)
/usr/sbin/sshd:
 Position Independent Executable: yes
 Stack protected: yes
 Fortify Source functions: yes (some protected functions found)
 Read-only relocations: yes
 Immediate binding: yes
```

Comment: Nice answer, also applicable to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and possibly other Ubuntu versions. `sudo apt-get install hardening-includes` and then the `hardening-check` executable perl script is available on the usual `PATH`(`/usr/bin/hardening-check`);  just a nit: Suggest to remove the `./` from the answer ;-)

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae not in 17.10 anymore :-(

Comment: In CentOS/RedHat, this package is available in [epel](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) repository

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae Looks like it is no longer available in Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: The debian package that contains this is now called `devscripts`.

Answer (score 28):

Simply use `file` on the binary:

```
$ file ./pie-off
./pie-off: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=0dc3858e9f0334060bfebcbe3e854909191d8bdc, not stripped
$ file ./pie-on
./pie-on: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.32, BuildID[sha1]=962235df5bd188e1ec48c151ff61b6435d395f89, not stripped
```

Note the different type printed after the LSB information.

Comment: How does this show if compiled with PIE/ASLR?

Comment: The only difference between the outputs from pie-off and pie.on are `executable` and `shared object`. I presume shared objects need to be relocatable hence to my mind have been compiled with PIE.

Comment: Yup, PIE executables are ELF shared objects; the easiest way to implement ASLR for executables was to use the existing support in the dynamic linker for and ELF entry point in a shared object.  See also [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427) for more about gcc options that control PIE, and that `gcc -fPIE -pie` is now the default on many distros.

Comment: Newer versions of file explicitly mention pie: e.g. ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=9b502fd78165cb04aec34c3f046c1ba808365a96, stripped

Comment: @PeterCordes note that `file` 5.36 now can actually recognize PIE-ness based on the `DT_1_PIE` flag of `DT_FLAGS_1`, and clearly says `pie executable` instead of `shared object`.

Comment: The `file` 5.38 version that ships with Ubuntu 20.04 does _not_ show `pie executable` reliably for me.

Answer (score 23):

**`file` 5.36 says it clearly**

`file` 5.36 actually prints it clearly if the executable is PIE or not. For example, a PIE executable shows as:

```
main.out: ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, not stripped
```

and a non-PIE one as:

```
main.out: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

The feature was introduced in 5.33 but it did just a simple `chmod +x` check. Before that it just printed `shared object` for PIE.

In 5.34, it was meant to start checking the more specialized `DF_1_PIE` ELF metadata, but due to a bug in the implementation it actually broke things and showed GCC PIE executables as `shared objects`.

I have interpreted `file` source code, including the bug, and exactly which bytes of the ELF format it checks in excruciating detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34519521/why-does-gcc-create-a-shared-object-instead-of-an-executable-binary-according-to/55704865#55704865

A quick summary of file 5.36 behavior is:

- if `Elf32_Ehdr.e_type == ET_EXEC`

  - print `executable`
- else if `Elf32_Ehdr.e_type == ET_DYN`

  - if `DT_FLAGS_1` dynamic section entry is present

    - if `DF_1_PIE` is set in `DT_FLAGS_1`:

      - print `pie executable`
    - else

      - print `shared object`
  - else

    - if file is executable by user, group or others

      - print `pie executable`
    - else

      - print `shared object`

**GDB run the executable twice and see ASLR**

One very direct thing that you can do is to run the executable twice through GDB and see if the address changes across runs due to ASLR.

I have explained how to do that in detail at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld/51308031#51308031

While this is not necessarily the most practical solution and not possible if you don't trust the executable, it is fun and it does the ultimate check that we really care about, which is if the Linux kernel / dynamic loader changes the executable location or not.

Comment: "address of main changes between runs" - this is not effect of pure PIE, it is PIE and enabled ASLR. Yes, it is almost anywhere enabled, but for machines with disabled ASLR address will be the same both times. ASLR may be enabled globally but disabled with `setarch -R` http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/setarch.8.html "`-R, --addr-no-randomize`  Disables randomization of the virtual address space.  Turns on `ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE`." http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/personality.2.html "`ADDR_NO_RANDOMIZE` (since Linux 2.6.12) With this flag set, disable address-space-layout randomization."

Answer (score 17):

I used `readelf --relocs` to test whether static or dynamic library is PIC on x86-64 the following way:

```
$ readelf --relocs /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/4.6/libstdc++.a |\
      awk '$3~/^R_/ && $5!~/^\.debug/{print $3}' |sort -u
R_X86_64_32
R_X86_64_32S
R_X86_64_64
R_X86_64_DTPOFF32
R_X86_64_GOTPCREL
R_X86_64_PC32
R_X86_64_PLT32
R_X86_64_TLSLD
R_X86_64_TPOFF32
```

We see here `R_X86_64_32` and `R_X86_64_32S`. This means that the code is not position independent. When I rebuild a library with -fPIC I get:

```
$ readelf --relocs libstdc++.a |\
      awk '$3~/^R_/ && $5!~/^\.debug/{print $3}' |sort -u
R_X86_64_64
R_X86_64_DTPOFF32
R_X86_64_GOTPCREL
R_X86_64_PC32
R_X86_64_PLT32
R_X86_64_TLSGD
R_X86_64_TLSLD
```

This method may probably work for executables, but I have not used it that way.

Comment: Would you care to explain how to interpret the output of that one-liner?  What's the criteria to use to classify the shared library as PIC vs non-PIC?

Comment: If you built an executable with `-fPIE -no-pie`, it would always be loaded at the same address even though it *could* have been linked as a PIE executable.  Use `file a.out` and look for `ELF executable` (non-PIE) vs. ELF shared object` (PIE):  [32-bit absolute addresses no longer allowed in x86-64 Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43367427)

Answer (score 9):

There is bash script [checksec.sh on Github](https://github.com/slimm609/checksec.sh) to check the executables mitigation properties (including RELRO, Stack Canary, NX bit, PIE, RPATH, RUNPATH, Fortify Source).

Run `checksec` with `-f` (file input) arguments:

```
$ checksec -f /usr/bin/bash

RELRO           STACK CANARY      NX            PIE             RPATH     RUNPATH      FORTIFY Fortified Fortifiable
Full RELRO      Canary found      NX enabled    PIE enabled     No RPATH   No RUNPATH    YES      13        33
```