# What is the difference between "LSB executable" (ET_EXEC) and "LSB shared object" (ET_DYN)?

Tags: gcc, elf, ld

With two files, one compiled and linked with `gcc` and the other manually with `nasm` and `ld` I get

- ELF 32-bit LSB shared object ...
- ELF 32-bit LSB executable ...

What's the difference between these two things? I can see with `readelf -h` that one is

- Type: `DYN (Shared object file)`
- Type: `EXEC (Executable file)`

I can see these documented on [Wikipedia as `ET_DYN` and `ET_EXEC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format#File_header). What are the practical differences between these two?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems this has something to do with Position Independent Executable (PIE). When GCC compiles executable by defaults it makes them PIE which changes the output flag on the ELF Header to `ET_DYN`.

You can disable the generation of PIE executables with

- `gcc -no-pie`

If you're seeing this check the default options gcc is configured with `gcc -v`, you should see something like `--enable-default-pie`.

*Answer inspired [by this submission on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34522357/124486).* I intend to play more with it and explain more here.

Answer (score 4):

It appears that the main effect of ET_EXEC vs ET_DYN in the Linux kernel / dynamic loader is to inform if the executable can be placed in random memory locations or not with ASLR.

As you concluded then, PIE executables are DYN, as they can be randomized, exactly like shared libraries.

I have explored this is more detail and:

- pointed to the relevant Linux kernel 5.0 code at: [How to test whether a Linux binary was compiled as position independent code?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/89211/how-to-test-whether-a-linux-binary-was-compiled-as-position-independent-code/435038#435038)
- shown how to observe PIE ASLR yourself at: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2463150/what-is-the-fpie-option-for-position-independent-executables-in-gcc-and-ld/51308031#51308031

Comment: Typo in first letter.

Comment: @Biswapriyo thanks! Always in a rush these days ;-)